# Ruby version potential conflicts for Heroku toolbelt

Tags: ruby, heroku, version, heroku-toolbelt

Currently, my installation of heroku toolbelt creates a ruby version of 1.9.2

But having installed via railsinstaller, my ruby version is 1.9.3.

When I deploy using heroku, will there be potential conflicts, and how can I prevent/manage/bypass them?

Comment: I get a folder called ruby 1.9.2 under my main heroku folder. perhaps it's just for backwards compatibility ensuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `heroku` command line tool is built in Ruby. Apparently they have done all of their testing on `ruby-1.9.2`.

This will not cause any compatibility issues with your application. If when you push to heroku, you notice that the application is using a different version other than `ruby-1.9.3`, add a `.ruby-version` file to the root of your application. That file should only have `ruby-1.9.3` in it.

Comment: I see, so that ruby 1.9.2 by heroku is for enabling heroku command lines, not running your app on.

Where would add the version? Are you talking about Gemfile, or adding a Ruby directory one level underneath the parent app directory?